# Dropdown menu align

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

im trying to create my own pure CCS+HTML dropdown menu. But dropdown part is alligned incorrectly, you can see this on page http://demo.dryga.com.

CSS:

```
#header-container > ul {
    float: right;
    padding: 6px 0 0 0;
}

#header-container > ul > li {
    display: inline;
}

#header-container > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 7px;
}

.language-selector > a {
    background:url('/images/arrow.png') no-repeat scroll right center;
    width: 60px;
}

.language-selector > ul {
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
}

.language-selector > ul > li {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">О программе</a></li>
    <li><a href="/videos/list.html">Курс</a></li>
    <li><a href="/faq.html">Помощь</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contacts.html">Контакты</a></li>
    <li class="language-selector">
        <a>Русский</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>English</a></li>
            <li><a>Deutch</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to align that part under last menu item?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CSS:

```
.language-selector > ul {
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
    top: 35px;
    left: 37px;
}

#header-container > ul > li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

It should do the trick!

The `position: relative;` is particularly important on every list element as that is what is used to position the dropdown menu.